# How to read all numbers in a file to an array?

Tags: c, arrays

If I have a file, full of integer elements, but the number of elements is unknown. I also don't know the upper limit of the elements.

So how can I read all the data into an array and print out the number of elements?

suppose all the element are separated by comma,i.e. elements are stored as

```
1, 2, 2, 5, 12, 11....
```

I've searched out this post: which it has an upper limit of the element.

The idea I came across is to use the code in the accepted answer, first count how many elements, then set the size of the array. Is this OK? Do you have better solutions?

Comment: If you're comfortable with other languages like java or python. These can be handled easily.

Comment: Allocate an initial amount of memory using malloc, read a number, and increment the counter. If counter is equal to the amount of allocated, realloc more memory. Repeat this process until `EOF`. Then, realloc counter amount of memory.

Comment: `suppose all the element are separated by comma` do you mean the file is a text file ?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is to first parse the file to count the number of elements, then allocate the array and then parse the file again to actually read the numbers.

Alternatively you can start with an initial size and realloc if it is too small. When reaching end-of-file, the last reallocated array may not be completely filled. You can then realloc the array to its final size, removing unused elements at the end, as user Zan Lynx suggested.

Comment: After the end of the file, you realloc to the final size. That removes the memory waste.

Comment: In practice, it is rarely useful to realloc and shrink the memory.  If you are increasing the buffer exponentially, it *might* be useful, but if you are increasing linearly (eg, just adding a fixed number of bytes with each allocation), there's no benefit to reallocating to shrink the buffer.

Comment: Everyone should reallocate by exponential growth. Doubling each time is easy and popular.

Comment: It seems that alternatively method is not as good as the first method, except the case when you've allocate enough memory at first time.